# Query not responding to order_by

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to order_by a query but i cannot seem to accomplish it, any help would be appreciated

```
users = User.objects.filter(Q(groups__name=group)).distinct()
```

This is the starting query i have tried many ways to make this work with the order_by method. But cant seem to get it working i am trying to order the query by the first_name in descending order.

```
.order_by('-first_name'.desc())
```

Something like this?

I get an error 'str' object has no attribute 'desc'

I have tried to look this up but cant see it being produced in the context that i am using it so i cant relate to the answers

-- Edit --

i have had some progress, Names are changing places but i cant seem to match a pattern, So i am thinking that (Q(groups__name=group)) could be the cause of it but i have no idea what this actually does, Can anyone explain this to me? thanks

Comment: Why have you added that `desc()`? You already have the `-`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Because neither of them are working

Comment: To go off your edit, you do not need the `Q()` if you are only doing one filter. `Q()` expressions are meant for using multiple filters and needs an `or` or `and` feature. So, you can remove that. Otherwise, your filter is looking at the `Groups` model, and specifically matching the `name` field with the `group` variable you are passing in that query. Does that make sense?

Comment: @jape Yeah thank you, it seems to be ordering them in groups, people who are engineers and other

Comment: Try printing generated SQL and see if it is correct. Like  print(User.objects.filter(Q(groups__name=group)).distinct().order_by('-first_name').query)

Comment: Yes, the way you currently have it, it will sort them by group (engineers, etc. as you mentioned). Within those groups, the people should be ordered by `'-first_name'`.

Comment: @jape it seems to be working, but i really needed it to re-list them all in alphabetical order, with the groups not playing a part within the order of the output. But i can live without them being in order. Thank you for trying to help me good sir!

Answer (score 1):

use

```
.order_by('-first_name')
```

instead of

```
.order_by('-first_name'.desc())
```

`-` stands for `descending` already. otherwise you are trying to call a method on a string instead of QuerySet object

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up, but unfortunatly it is still not working for me, Could this have something to do with (Q(groups__name=group)) this section of codE?